# many to many form, mongoid & rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, mongoid, simple-form

I have 2 models in my app. A Shopping_list and a Product

The shopping list can contain many products, a product can be a part of many shopping lists.

The shopping list -

```
class Shopping_list
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, :type => String
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end
```

And the product

```
class Product
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, :type => String
  has_and_belongs_to_many :shopping_lists
end
```

If a user visits /shopping_list/some_id/edit I want them to see  -

```
a) The name of the product in a text box
b) A series of checkboxes listing all of the products that they can check to add to that list.
c) A submit button.
```

My controller looks like this

```
def edit
  @shopping_list = Shopping_list.find(params[:id])
  render :action => 'edit'
end
```

My view looks like this

```
<%= simple_form_for(@shopping_list) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :articles, :as => :check_boxes %> #I know this is completely wrong. What do I do to fix?
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

This does not work at all and I'm a bit stumped. Not sure how to proceed while using Mongoid.

Advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<%= simple_form_for(@shopping_list) do |f| %>
   <%= f.input :name %>
   <%= f.association :products,:collection => @shopping_list.products.collect{ |p| [p.name, p.id] }, :as => :check_boxes %>
   <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks. It was the 'association' that I was looking for.